# Проверка при добавлении записи MySQL

Tags: mysql

Сделал триггер при добавлении записи в таблицу. Но как то работает он не правильно

```
BEGIN
IF (NEW.id_user != -1) THEN
 INSERT INTO users (id_user, name) 
 VALUES (NEW.id_user, NEW.name);
END IF;
END
```

Этот триггер должен добавлять запись, если id_user НЕ равен -1. Но почему то все происходит наоборот - если РАВЕН -1 то добавляет, а в остальных случаях нет. Или я что-то неправильно понял? И еще вопрос, можно ли как то не писать конструкцию на добавление в триггере если условие верно, а просто разрешить добавление?

Comment: А на какую таблицу у вас триггер, надеюсь не на эту же самую users ?

Comment: На эту. А что не так?

Comment: Эта таблица, просто в качестве примера. Но вообще нужно сделать, что бы в столбец id_user нельзя было добавить значение, которое уже существует, за исключением значения -1. То есть -1 может встречаться сколь угодно раз, но вот другие значения могут быть только по одному(не может быть несколько значений 2 например)

Comment: @NoName Чем определяется значение '-1'? Нельзя ли вместо него в качестве "добавляй сколько нужно" использовать NULL? Тогда с поставленной задачей легко справится обычный UNIQUE INDEX. Иначе - нужно не устраивать в триггере "пляски по кругу", а генерировать ошибку, которая не даст выполниться процессу добавления.

Comment: Когда срабатывает триггер запись уже практически вставлена в таблицу и повторять это действие триггер уже не должен. И вообще триггер не имеет права обращаться к той таблице на которую он написан. Если надо отменить производимое действие,  то триггер должен, как правильно заметил Akina, сгенерировать ошибку. И да, для подобных целей как у вас в БД придумано значение NULL, не надо использовать ничего другого

Comment: А почему нельзя обращаться из триггера к той таблице, на которую написан триггер?

Comment: чтобы не было бесконечного цикла: триггер вызывает обращение к таблице, которое вызывает тригер, и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

для предотвращения записи используйте [signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html), в старых версиях генерите ошибку, например, обращением к несуществующей таблице.